# issue when using jQuery library 1.10.2 vs. fiddle with 1.7.2

Tags: jquery

In this project, users can add and edit tags. There's a tag container, an edit textbox and button, and an add textbox and button. I have a select list that keeps track of the changes, with the database id of the tags in its index.

When I run my code with my version of jQuery library (1.10.2) - the click between tag buttons doesn't affect the list all the time. In fact, only the first button click changes the selected item in the list.

When I apply this code to a fiddle with a jQuery library (1.7.2) lower than mine - the list responds as I would expect, changing its selected item as you click a tag button.

Here's my code, along with the working fiddle. Switching between jQuery libraries in the fiddle will demonstrate the issue:

HTML:

```
        <!-- tags container -->
        <div class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_2"><img src="images/spacer.png" /></div>
            <div id="content" class="grid_8">
                <button id="PHP" name="PHP" class="tag-button">PHP</button>
                <button id="CSS" name="CSS" class="tag-button">CSS</button>

            </div>
            <div class="grid_2"><img src="images/spacer.png" /></div>
        </div>
        <!-- tags container end -->

        <!-- action buttons container -->
        <div class="container_12 action-bar">
            <div class="grid_4"><img src="images/spacer.png" /></div>
           <div id="action-add">
                <input type="text" name="newTag" id="newTag" />
                <input type="button" id="add" value="Add tag" />
            </div>
            <div class="grid_4"><img src="images/spacer.png" /></div>
            <div id="action-edit">
                <input type="text" name="editTag" id="editTag" />
                <input type="button" id="update" value="Update tag" />
            </div>
        <!-- action buttons container end -->
        </div>

        <!-- Real Time list container -->
        <div class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_4"><img src="images/spacer.png" /></div>
            <select id="insertString">
                <option value="0">PHP</option>
                <option value="1">CSS</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- real time list container end -->
```

jQuery:

```
       //button add click
        $('#add').click(function() {
            //creating a new tag for the tag bar
            var tag = $('#newTag').val();
            var tagHTML=$('<button name= "' + tag + '" class="tag-button">'+ tag + '</button>');
            var qString = "";
            // adding the tag to the bar
            $("#content").append(tagHTML);

            //get last value in the list
            var lastValue = $('#insertString option:last-child').val();
            if (! lastValue) {lastValue = 0;}
            else {lastValue = ++ lastValue; }
            //add new option for the new tag
            $('<option value="' + lastValue + '">' + tag + '</option>').appendTo("#insertString")
        })

        //tag button click
        $("#content").on("click", ".tag-button", function(){
            var name = $(this).attr('name');

            //add the tag name to the editTag textbox
            $('#editTag').val(name);

            $('#insertString option:contains("'+ name + '")').attr('selected', true);
        });

        //update button click
        $('#update').click(function() {
            //get the name of the edited tag in the list
            var tagName = $('#insertString').find(':selected').text();
            var tagNew = $('#editTag').val();

            //change the corresponding buttons name, id and text
            $('#' + tagName).text(tagNew);

            $('#' + tagName).attr({
                name: tagNew,
                id: tagNew
            });

            //change option in the list
            $('#insertString option:selected').text(tagNew);

        })
```

And the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gWnu5/1/

Is there any way to get this code working on my version of jQuery?

Thank you for your help

Comment: attr vs prop is your problem. read over the http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

Comment: Thank you Kevin, for your respectful response. I wasn't sure if it was in fact a bug or what. Searching for it didn't get me anything on google... I might have not phrased the search appropriately. Again, thank you for being respectful :)

Comment: the fact that you're going from 1.7.2 to 1.10 does make finding documentation for that difficult, since there is no 1.10 upgrade guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Kevin B, really. This is a prop vs. attr issue - updated my code to fit newest library of jQuery core, and all is well. Link of note was: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-

JQuery being brand new to me, this was invaluable information. Passing it along.